# How to check duplicate value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

I have one table as below:

```html
ID   USER1    USER2
1      Q        Y
2      W        Y 
3      R        Y
4      T        Y
5      XY       Y
```

How I can check when USER2 column is ALL duplicate ? I'm using this code but It not working

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COMLUMN FROM TABLE");
$result = array_unique($res);
if($result == 1 )
{
echo "Unique";
}
else
{
echo "NOT Unique";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a:

```
SELECT COUNT(USER2) FROM tablename GROUP BY USER2
```

And see if it returns 1 record, or the first record value is equal to the total record count.

Here is an example:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(USER2) FROM tablename GROUP BY USER2 LIMIT 1) = (SELECT COUNT(USER2) FROM tablename)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->fetch_row()[0] == 1)
{
  // all same
}
else
{
  //not same
}
```

Comment: You can show more PHP code ? I do but not working :
$res = "SELECT COUNT(USER2) FROM tablename GROUP BY USER2"
if($res ==1) {echo "Is 1";} else {echo "More";}

Comment: Hey Ivan, sorry for the delay:

Answer (score 1):

suppose you are trying to find `USER2` column duplicate values, then try this query

```
SELECT tableName.*, COUNT(*) AS duplicate_count FROM tableName 
GROUP BY USER2
HAVING duplicate_count > 1
```

this query return all duplicate `USER2` rows

Answer (score 1):

Assuming USER2 column is declared to be NOT NULL, or if it doesn't contain NULL values or if you want to ignore NULL values... then one of the easiest queries to accomplish the check would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.USER2) AS cnt FROM `TABLE` t
```

Just fetch the row returned from the query, and compare `cnt` to 1, if it's greater than 1, then there is more than one different non-null values.

In the more general case, when you do want to consider NULL values, then you'd likely want to use a GROUP BY query. I'd probably use a query like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM ( SELECT t.USER2 AS val FROM `TABLE` t GROUP BY t.USER2 ) s
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(USER2) as temp from table group by USER2 having temp='1'

if any results is returned then is uniq.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to check whether another row with a different `user2` value exists. If not, then all values are the same. For larger tables using `exists` to check if there's are at least one pair of distinct values may be faster than getting the total # of distinct values.

```
select case when exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1
    where exists (
        select 1 from mytable t2
        where t2.user2 <> t1.user2
    )
) then 'not unique' else 'unique'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT COUNT(USER2) - COUNT(DISTINCT USER2) FROM tableName
```

If result equals `0` then there is no duplicates.